# Converting Chlorine Dioxide to Free Residual Chlorine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Our water treatment facility used Chlorine Dioxide to disinfect the produced drinking water. The analysis results indicate concentrations of 0.2 mg/l of chlorine dioxide at the source. Can we analys residual chlorine in the distribution network? We dont have water quality standards for chlorine dioxide, only residual chlorine. Can I calculate the concentration of chlorine in the water from the concentration of chlorine dioxide?

Answer (score -1):

Some chemistry, first add H2O2 and NaOH:

> $\ce{2 ClO2 + H2O2 + 2 NaOH -> 2 NaClO2 + O2 (g) + 2 H2O }$

Source: https://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-1114

Continue adding H2O2, as:

> $\ce{2 NaClO2 + 2 H2O2 ->  2 NaClO + 2 O2 (g) + 2 H2O }$
>
> $\ce{2 NaClO + 2 H2O2 -> 2 NaCl + 2 O2 (g) + 2 H2O }$

which implies a net reaction of:

> $\ce{2 ClO2 + 5 H2O2 + 2 NaOH -> 2 NaCl + 5 O2 (g) + 6 H2O }$

So, slowly add H2O2 until the bubbling ceases. Collect the volume of oxygen and convert to moles. Divide by 2.5 to determine moles of ClO2 and your chlorine therefrom.

Here is a related reference, [Titrimetric and photometric methods for determination of hypochlorite in commercial bleaches](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10934521003772295?scroll=top&needAccess=true&journalCode=lesa20), which cites the use of hydrogen peroxide and acidic permanganate.

Comment: Please have a look at [Is ChemiDay a reliable enough source (for inorganic reactions) to be cited on our site?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/is-chemiday-a-reliable-enough-source-for-inorganic-reactions-to-be-cited-on-ou)

Comment: The action of H2O2 on NaOCl has to be one of the better-known reactions.  The reaction mechanics is actually more complex than many are aware, but the final products are not in dispute.

Comment: Also, do not employ concentrated H2O2, dilute solutions are safer especially in forming normal dioxygen (not singlet oxygen).